# Considerar strings nulas e vazias como equivalentes entre si

Tags: c#

Desejo comparar strings que vêm de duas fontes diferentes. Se forem diferentes, irei fazer alguma coisa. Mais ou menos assim:

```
if (foo != bar)
{
    noop();
}
```

Porém, no meu caso específico, estou a considerar que uma string vazia e uma string nula são a mesma coisa. Em certas linguagens como Javascript um código assim já bastaria, mas não é dessa forma que a coisa funciona no mundo .NET...

```
string foo = null;
string bar = "";
foo == bar; // false;
```

Eu sei que posso resolver meu problema com alguma pré-conversão do tipo:

```
foo = (foo != null ? foo : "");
bar = (bar != null ? bar : "");
```

Mas isso me incomoda, pois me parece excessivo. Existe alguma forma mais minimalista de se fazer uma comparação que considere nulo ou vazio como a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se só lhe interessa um resultado binário, se são iguais ou não, porque não fazer:

```
bool iguais = string.IsNullOrEmpty(primeiraString) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(segundaString);
```

Desta forma, se as strings forem nulas, nula/vazia ou vazias, `iguais` vai ficar a `true`.

Edit:

Um exemplo no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uwdImg).

Comment: Boa. Isso se aproxima suficiente do que eu quero. Vou criar um método que faz essa verificação, e em caso de falso, compara as strings entre si.

Answer (score 2):

Se for utilizar em mais de um lugar, eis uma implementação baseada numa [resposta do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1797610/916193).

```
static class Comparacao
{
    public static bool SaoIguais(string a, string b)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(b);
        }
        return string.Equals(a, b);
    }
}
```